# Symfony 2 / Doctrine - error with the command : php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I tried couple stuff in internet, but no one solution resolved my problem.

I'm learning symfony 2 and doctrine for using database. I wanted to generate my new tables with this command :

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

But I have this Exception error on my console :

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                    
Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's 
timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or  
the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods 
and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the 
timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CEST/2.0/DST' instead 
in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SdzBlog/Symfony/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/
Logger.php line 209
```

About my configuration : 
I use MAMP for my server
My OS is MAC OS 10.8.5

I think that it's about php.ini, but I can't edit this files. It's telling me that these files are read-only when I try to edit them. I even tried to make chmod in order to be able to edit them, and I still have read-only message.

Does someone know how to resolve this issue please ?

Thanks

**ANSWER : Read the answer of Nicolai, and all his comments, it helps**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize configuration parameter date.timezone in your php.ini. 
You  must open your php.ini with superuser privileges. eg.

```
sudo mcedit /private/etc/php.ini
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I could edit the file thanks to your command. Nevertheless, I still have the exception.
For the timezone I put `date.timezone = US/Pacific` 
Maybe MAMP use another php.ini ? Not the one that is inside the path /private/etc/ ? I read some stuff in the web about that. It's kind of confusing, there is php of the mac os, and php of MAMP I think. I'm not sure.

Comment: To find your php.ini run command `php -i|grep 'php.ini'`. Or create a page with only one function `phpinfo();` when you open this page it will show you a lot of information about your PHP and location of php.ini too.

Comment: I tried both. For the phpinfo(), because it's php of MAMP, for the configuration file loaded is `"/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/conf/php.ini"`, but if I try the command `php -i|grep 'php.ini` I have this output `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /private/etc/php.ini
PHP Warning:  Unknown: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. Yo....`The warning is exactly the same than I put in the description of my issue :S
Timezone for /private/etc/php.ini = date.timezone = "US/Pacific"
Timezone for php.ini of MAMP bin = "US/Pacific" as well

Comment: Are you sure that parameter `date.timezone` in `/private/etc/php.ini` is not commented?

Comment: I opened again `/private/etc/php.ini` and for `[Date]` part, the output is : `; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions                       
; http://php.net/date.timezone                                                  
;date.timezone = "US/Pacific"` 
Before your tips, before editing this file, the date.timezone was empty. So output was : 
`date.timezone = `
The current date.timezone seems to be set correctly. I don't know why the issue still exists

Comment: `;date.timezone = ` - is threre symbol ';' in the beginning of the line? If yes, is means that line is commented. Remove this symbol ';' from  beginning of the string.

Comment: IT WORKS !!! Thank you very much for your patience and your help. I don't know why I couldn't figure it out by myself this stupid mistake lol. We could resolve it thanks to your steps ! Thank you